# Filter Options: All selection

Tags: rally

I have created a filter based upon the state for my grid.  However, I cannot figure out a way to see all the tasks regardless of state.  Is there a way to add an all option to the filter so it will show tasks from all the states?  This is the code I have so far

```
                        xtype : 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
                        itemId : 'stateComboBox',
                        fieldLabel : 'Filter by State:',
                        model : 'task',
                        field : 'State',
                        listeners : {
                            select : this._onSelect1,
                            ready : this._onLoad1,
                            scope : this
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. In this combobox I set `allowNoEntry: true`, and use it in place of "all". When NoEntry is selected the combobox returns null. I check for that condition in  `_getStateFilter`.

If combobox returns null then `_getStateFilter` returns empty filter, which effectively removes all filtering by State and returns all tasks regardless of State value.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
            itemId: 'stateComboBox',
            fieldLabel: 'Filter by State:',
            model: 'Task',
            field: 'State',
            allowNoEntry: true,
            listeners: {
                select: this._onSelect,
                ready: this._onLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },

    _onLoad: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            columnCfgs: [
                'FormattedID',
                'Name',
                'State'
            ],
            context: this.getContext(),
            storeConfig:  {
                model: 'task',
                context: this.context.getDataContext(),
                filters: [this._getStateFilter()]
            }
        });
    },

    _getStateFilter: function() {
        if (!this.down('#stateComboBox').getValue()) {
            return {}
        }
        else{
            return {
            property: 'State',
            operator: '=',
            value: this.down('#stateComboBox').getValue()
        };
        }

    },

    _onSelect: function() {
        var grid = this.down('rallygrid'),
            store = grid.getStore();

        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filter(this._getStateFilter());
    }
});
```